# AngularJs - bind one ng-model to directive with two inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-directive

How to create a `range` directive which binds to one `ng-model` and outputs two `input` fields using a `filter` (already made). Essentially I've got one direction *from model to input* working, but the other side *from input to model* not. How to achieve this?

I've got this Html:

```
<div tu-range ng-model="arbitraymodel" />
```

And a model:

```
var arbitrarymodel = "10/22";
```

Side note; I created a filter to split those two values: 

`{{ feature.Value | split:\'/\':0}}`

And this directive:

```
.directive('tuRange', function($compile) {
    return { 
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            feature: '=',
            tudisabled: '=',
            model: '=ngModel' // edited
        },
        template: '<input type="text" '+
               'ng-value="{{ model | split:\'/\':0}}" />'+ // edited to 'model'
             '-<input type="text" '+
               'ng-value="{{ model | split:\'/\':1}}" />', // edited to 'model'
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Do you really *need* to do it with the value of `10/22`? Why don't use an Object for that, with `arbitrary.begin` and `arbitrary.end` keys? You can combine both back to one value if you want with a change listener.

Comment: hm, not so sure about this, but how does he reverse the filtering for the two way binding?

Comment: I made a small change to the directive scope adding `model`. @ConcurrentHashMap Yes it's not the most optimal data I get. But eventually it has to be send back that way, so to make sure everything happens in one place, I'd like to do it in the directive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way (IMO) is to create a custom control as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

As an exercise, I implemented it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cn7y/

The code of the directive is (you may need to adapt some details):

```
app.directive("range", function() {
    var ID=0;

    function constructRangeString(from, to) {
        var result;
        if( !from && !to ) {
            result = null;
        }
        else if( from ) {
            result = from + "/" + (to || "");
        }
        else if( to ) {
            result = "/" + to;
        }
        return result;
    }

    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: "@"
        },
        template:
            '<div ng-form="{{ subFormName }}">' +
                '<input type="text" ng-model="from" class="range-from" />' +
                '<input type="text" ng-model="to" class="range-to" />' +
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
            var re = /([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/;

            if( scope.name ) {
                scope.subFormName = scope.name;
            }
            else {
                scope.subFormName = "_range" + ID;
                ID++;
            }

            ngModel.$render = function() {
                var result, from, to;
                result = re.exec(ngModel.$viewValue);
                if( result ) {
                    from = parseInt(result[1]);
                    to = parseInt(result[2]);
                }
                scope.from = from;
                scope.to = to;
            };

            scope.$watch("from", function(newval) {
                var result = constructRangeString(newval, scope.to);
                ngModel.$setViewValue(result);
            });
            scope.$watch("to", function(newval) {
                var result = constructRangeString(scope.from, newval);
                ngModel.$setViewValue(result);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And its usage would be:

```
<range ng-model="ctrl.theRange" name="myRange" required="true"></range>
```

---

I doubt the filters will get you anywhere with this, as they do not do 2-way binding.

---

**EDIT**: Even though this solves the problem, I would suggest a slightly different approach. I would define the model of the `range` directive as an object:

```
{
    from: ...,
    to:   ...
}
```

This means that the output in the `ctrl.theRange` variable in the example would be an object like that of the above. If you really want the string format `"from/to"`, add a parser/formatter in the `ngModel` pipelines, i.e. the `constructRangeString()` function. Using the parser/formatter, the `ctrl.theRange` variable gets the desired string format, while keeping the code more modularized (the `constructRangeString()` function is external to the directive) and more parameterized (the model is in a format that can easilly be processed and transformed).

And a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/W99rX/

Comment: Wow, very nicely done. I especially like the second way which is indeed more modular, thus better testable aswell. Thank you so much!

Comment: Few comments: 1. If you fill in '0' the model goes empty because you check for `if(!from && !to) return null;` which results in an empty model. 

2. when using around 180 ranges (because it's a data grid), it's very slow.

Comment: 1. Yes I expect a few rough edges. Another could be the regular expression. And you may need to `unshift()` from the `$formatters` instead of `push`ing - I keep getting confused with this. 2. This is interesting (and unfortunate). One optimization I would try is to take the view values directly with the DOM events and not using the nested form and `ng-model`s. This will reduce the watches but complicate the code. Another optimization is to try to replace the deep watch with 2 separate watches for `"from"` and `"to"`. I do not expect it to do much, but you never know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried a few optimizations, also with removing the `RexExp`, but in the end it was slow. So I took the set I got through a `$http()` and modified the values using `value.split('/')` (with a few checks) and put it in the global `model.from`/`.to`, and even now it's still slow. So I guess I have to cope with it. Or maybe only update the `model` using a `ng-blur` to update the values. I have to see what to do :). Thank you so much so far :)

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around the intricacies of Angular directives. I thought that the `$render` method was used to update the html. So why do you set the `scope.from` and `scope.to` variables inside of the `$render` method instead of doing something like `element.find('input').eq(0).val(from)` (and similarly for `to`)?

Comment: It is a convenience because the template of the custom control is using `ng-model` in its inputs. Indeed it is not only possible, but also potentially more performant to use DOM manipulation here, because of less watches. On the downside, it requires more code: Not only the one way in `$render`, but also the other way: you have to listen to the appropriate events of the inputs and trigger model updates. If you want to be concise with Angular, you will also need to honour `ng-model-options`.

Comment: The jsFiddle referenced above (http://jsfiddle.net/W99rX/) works for angular version 1.2.x but I found I couldn't get it to work in in Angular 1.4.x After some reading of the docs I changed the line that reads ngModel.$setViewValue(newval); to ngModel.$setViewValue(angular.copy(newval)); and it worked as expected.