# input fields formating using filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, format, angularjs-filter

I have gone through many links and forums but still not able to finalize whether a filter in angularjs can be used to format a input field. I have seen filters for formatting for the data from the scope to the view either through a controller or a directive.
But is filter an option to format a value in the input text as and when we enter values in that field ?

I believe the directive with a parser and formatter is able to do the formatting of an input.

I am entering a value as  11031988, once I enter the value, which can format the value in the field as 11/03/1988 , either a filter or a directive ?

Comment: Code you post some code? Better still a plunkr?

Comment: No, filters are not the tool for this job. Use the directive and the `$parsers`/`$formatters` pipelines, as you say. See a recent [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141773/angularjs-bind-one-ng-model-to-directive-with-two-inputs/25142660#25142660).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code snippet that formats the date as it is being typed. The digits will automatically be put into format. You can run this code to see what I mean:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {});

app.directive('inputRestrictor', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
        var pattern = /[^0-9]/g;
        
        function fromUser(text) {
          if (!text)
            return text;
          var transformedInput = text.replace(pattern, '');
          transformedInput = transformedInput.replace(/^([0-9]{0,8}).*$/, "$1");
          transformedInput = transformedInput.replace(
              /([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{0,4}$)/, "$1/$2/$3")
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
          return transformedInput;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.2" src="  https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="inputValue" input-restrictor>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="getdata()" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```