# How to bind one model to multiple inputs with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an form input which is for a MySQL date field. Ex: `2015-01-31`.

I want to allow the user to input this using 3 different form inputs. One for the year, one for the month, and one for the day.

Obviously ng-model isn't going to work right out of the box, because I'm trying to bind just one *part* of the date string to each input. I'm pretty sure the way to do it is bye creating three "temporary" scope vars/models

```
$scope.year;
$scope.month;
$scope.day;
```

...and then somehow combine/binding them to the actual value.

```
//If only it were this easy!
$scope.date = $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.day;
```

The line above of course won't work because the values aren't two-way-bound. If the form were only for saving new data, I could could get away with that by just combining the inputs on submit. But I need it to handle/show existing data also. And it's going to get super ugly if I can't figure out a way to wrangle Angular's binding magic to do what I want.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141773/angularjs-bind-one-ng-model-to-directive-with-two-inputs) which I think is trying to do the same thing, but they solve it with a custom directive, which is something I'm hoping to avoid. I know this may be a more maintainable/portable/modular way to do it, but I'm new to Angular and a bit intimidated by that. Also, the inputs are using the lovely [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) directive, which adds an additional layer of complexity to that approach.

Comment: The simplest solution is to have 3 scope properties and then combine them. When you fetch the date form your api, you will need to split the field up and set each scope property. You can create a re-usable directive to do this so it can be used in more than one place

Comment: I think a reusable directive that contains the three fields and converts from/to a single date field should be the way to go. But why don't you use a date picker such as ui.bootstrap.datepicker ?

Comment: @WayneEllery is it going to be messy to create a directive and still use angular-selectize?

Comment: @ps0604 As I said in my question, I agree that a directive is probably "better" but I just don't know how to do it. And I suspect it will be tricky to integrate with angular-selectize. If it's not as hard to do as I think I'm open to it. I'll leave the datepicker discussion for another time.

Comment: It's not that tricky, you would just use angular-selectize in your directive instead of using a normal select. Without a directive it's much simpler but using a directive is recommended so that it can be re-used.

Comment: @WayneEllery Would you consider submitting an answer showing what that might look like?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on it. I'm quite new to creating directives myself

Comment: Cool. It's the dependency injection I'm least comfortable with. I'm also a but fuzzy on how the $scope/binding works but there seems to be a lot of good documentation.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use bootstrap datepicker? Formally I'd just use bootstrap for this kind of thing, rather than trying to re-write a date field

Comment: @WayneEllery there's a handful of reasons why I don't want to use a datepicker, but I don't want to get into it here because it's a UI decision that has nothing to do with my question. If you're really curious, chat/message me and I'll tell you about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69538/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-sdp).

Comment: If you're too intimidated to use directives and create one yourself then you will definitely miss one of the core parts that makes AngularJS superior from any other frameworks. I recommend you to read the [developer's guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and the [$compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: @ryeballar I probably should have said "not comfortable with directives yet" because I'm not opposed. I just wanted to be clear that didn't really know how to do it and my use case has some addition complexity from the selectize dependency. So an answer like "just use a directive" wouldn't have helped me. But there are some really thorough answers below that make it look quite doable

Comment: @WayneEllery one reason not to use a premade datepicker is because what if we aren't dealing with a date? Date is part of the question, but irrelevant in my case where I am trying to do exactly the same thing, but with inches, ie. one `select` for whole inch size (3) one `select` for decimal/fraction inch size (.125) giving me a final size of 3.125 or 3 1/8 which is used for display.

Comment: @pspahn That is a lot simpler than trying to provide selects to select a date. I'd suggest to create a directive that has the two selects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A directive is probably best, but these examples look overly complex. Anyway if you are hoping to avoid a directive, just use `$scope.$watch` and re-build your date string each time one of the important variables are updated.

Something like this might be in your controller:

```
$scope.year = '';
$scope.month = '';
$scope.day = '';

// this might be able to be refactored
$scope.$watch('year', buildDate);
$scope.$watch('month', buildDate);
$scope.$watch('day', buildDate);

function buildDate() {
  $scope.date = $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.day;
}
```

As a side note, this is probably what my directive logic would look like too.

Edit: Code cleanup and fiddle

Cleaner example - I prefer this because it groups all the date-related items with an object, which also makes watching for changes easier.

```
$scope.date = {
    year: '',
    month: '',
    day: ''
};

// use watch collection to watch properties on the main 'date' object
$scope.$watchCollection('date', buildDate);

function buildDate(date) {
  $scope.dateString = date.year + "-" + date.month + "-" + date.day;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10g9kv9b/3/)

Comment: To handle pre-existing values would you add another function like `parseDate()` to extract the parts of the date string and preset the values?

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a great option. At that point you might even consider creating a Date service to house all that similar logic.

Answer (score 5):

here's an interesting demo that uses custom directives that are a lot less intimidating than the ones you linked to. You should be able to apply them to your inputs without too much conflict with other stuff:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3a8xnCfJFJrBlDRTUBG7?p=preview

The trick is setting the parser and formatter for a model using the directive. This lets you intercept changes to the model and interact with the rest of your scope:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.date = new Date();
});

app.directive('datePartInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      var part = attrs.part;
      var modelToUser, userToModel
      console.log('part:', part);
      if (part == 'year') {
        modelToUser = function(date) {
          return date.getFullYear();
        }
        userToModel = function(year) {
          ngModel.$modelValue.setYear(year);
          return ngModel.$modelValue
        }
      }
      else if (part == 'month') {
        modelToUser = function(date) {
          return date.getMonth();
        }
        userToModel = function(month) {
          ngModel.$modelValue.setMonth(month);
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        }
      }
      else if (part == 'day') {
        modelToUser = function(date) {
          return date.getUTCDate();
        };
        userToModel = function(day) {
          ngModel.$modelValue.setUTCDate(day);
          return ngModel.$modelValue;
        };
      }
      ngModel.$formatters.push(modelToUser);
      ngModel.$parsers.push(userToModel);
    }
  }
})
```

And the template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  {{date |  date}}
  <input date-part-input part="year" ng-model="date">
  <input date-part-input part="month" ng-model="date">
  <input date-part-input part="day" ng-model="date">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a re-usable directive that has the three fields in it so it can be used for all date fields. The model for the directive is aliased to `date` on the isolated scope. To get each of the date parts the date is then split and then `year`, `month` and `day` are assigned to scope properties. Then when one of the fields is changed the date property is updated by appending them together with the `-` separator.

For this directive I've just hard coded, years months and days. I'd recommend to use some javascript date functions to populate them so they aren't hard coded.

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive('dateSelect', function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          date:'=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<div class="dateSelect"><div class="dateField"><selectize placeholder="Select a year..." config="yearConfig" ng-model="year" ng-change="dateChanged()"></selectize></div>' +
        '<div class="dateField"><selectize placeholder="Select a month..." config="monthConfig" ng-model="month" ng-change="dateChanged()"></selectize></div>' + 
        '<div class="dateField"><selectize placeholder="Select a day..." config="dayConfig" ng-model="day" ng-change="dateChanged()"></selectize></div></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.yearConfig = {
          options: [{value: 2013, text: '2013'}, {value: 2014, text:'2014'}, {value: 2015, text:'2015'}],
          create: true,
          sortField: 'value',
          maxItems: 1,
        };
        $scope.monthConfig = {
          options: [{value: '01', text: '1'}, {value: '02', text: '2'}, {value: '03', text:'3'}, 
          {value: '04', text: '4'}, {value: '05', text:'5'}, {value: '06', text:'6'}, {value: '07', text: '7'}, {value: '08', text:'8'}, {value: '09', text:'9'},
          {value: '10', text: '10'}, {value: '11', text:'11'}, {value: '12', text:'12'}],
          create: true,
          sortField: 'value',
          maxItems: 1,
        };

        $scope.dayConfig = {
          options: [{value: '01', text: '1'}, {value: '02', text: '2'}, {value: '03', text:'3'}, 
          {value: '04', text: '4'}, {value: '05', text:'5'}, {value: '06', text:'6'}, {value: '07', text: '7'}, {value: '08', text:'8'}, {value: '09', text:'9'},
          {value: '10', text: '10'}, {value: '11', text:'11'}, {value: '12', text:'12'}],
          create: true,
          sortField: 'value',
          maxItems: 1,
        };

        $scope.dateChanged = function () {
          if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.year) && !angular.isUndefined($scope.month) && !angular.isUndefined($scope.day)) {
            $scope.date = $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.day;
          }
        }

        if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.date)) {
          var dateParts = $scope.date.split("-");

          if (dateParts.length === 3) {
            $scope.year = dateParts[0];
            $scope.month = dateParts[1];
            $scope.day = dateParts[2];
          }
        }
      }
    };
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6AwXo3tuppyPyVpA8E5j?p=preview)

Comment: That looks pretty doable! Would I need to inject the selectize dependency on for that to work? Or does that stay on the parent module?

Comment: No. You only need to add selectize to the module. If the directive is in the same module of your app then you are good to go.