# Proper way to $watch external changes to a ngModel from inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I'm trying to make a directive that reads from two input sources and do some stuff to turn it into one. So to do that I'm listening to the changes of my two inputs and assigning the new combined value to the ngModel of my directive.

The problem is that I also need to know when the ngModel is modified outside the directive to do the reverse process and properly set the values of my two directive input sources. There is a proper way to do that?

I made a snippet to better illustrate the problem, this isn't my actual directive.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])

.controller('AppController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = {
    value: ''
  };
  
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.data.value = 'hellooooo';
  }, 5000);
})

.directive('sampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input ng-model="data.input1" ng-change="changed()"><input ng-model="data.input2" ng-change="changed()">',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.data = {};
      $scope.changed = function() {
        $scope.ngModel = $scope.data.input1 + ' + ' + $scope.data.input2;  
      }
      
      // The watch is running even when the ngModel is modified inside the changed function above 
      // I want it to only run when the model is changed from outside the directive, like
      // I'm doing in the AppController.
      $scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value) {
        if (value) {
          // Just simulating some processing
          var length = value.length;
          
          $scope.data.input1 = value.slice(0, length/2);
          $scope.data.input2 = value.slice(length/2, length-1);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myapp">
  
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <sample-directive ng-model="data.value"></sample-directive>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div>{{ data.value }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: A different solution for your problem using the ngModel controller is presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141773/angularjs-bind-one-ng-model-to-directive-with-two-inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a custom input control. It is an input control that has 2 textboxes, but the "model" is really for a combination of both.

To implement a custom input control that "supports" `ngModel`, i.e. integrates with other directives that `require: ngModel`, your directive also needs to `require: ngModel` and use the `ngModelController` hooks to integrate.

So, don't just do `scope: { ngModel: "=" }`. With this, you are two-way-binding to a model attached to the `ng-model` attribute, but things would not work as you expect them when you set this value with `scope.ngModel = "something"`.

Angular provides an [example of a custom input control](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) in its documentation of [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). In a nutshell, you will need to orchestrate setting the `$viewValue` - when the underlying View changes, and setting the View - when the model changes.

```
.directive("sampleDirective", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: true,
    template: '<input ng-model="d.input1" ng-change="viewChanged()">\
               <input ng-model="d.input2" ng-change="viewChanged()">',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      var d = scope.d = {};      

      ngModel.$render = render;

      scope.viewChanged = read;


      // defines how to render based on model changes
      function render(){
        var modelValue = ngModel.$modelValue || "";
        var length = modelValue.length;

        d.input1 = modelValue.slice(0, length/2);
        d.input2 = length > 1 ? modelValue.slice(length/2, length) : "";
      };


      // defines how to set the model based on DOM changes
      function read(){
        var newViewValue = d.input1 + d.input2;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newViewValue);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Then, your control would work with any other directive that supports `ngModel`, like `required` or `ng-pattern` or `ng-change`, and could participate in form validations:

```
<div ng-form="form1">
  <sample-directive ng-model="foo" maxlength="8" ng-change="doSomething()">
  </sample-directive>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zsuwvJQPILMtNf4y9lt6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Rather strange requirement but you can change your directive to use the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) instead

```
.directive('sampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input ng-model="data.input1" ng-change="changed()"><input ng-model="data.input2" ng-change="changed()">',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
      // This will be called when it is changed from outside the directive
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (value) {
          // Just simulating some processing
          var length = value.length;

          scope.data.input1 = value.slice(0, length/2);
          scope.data.input2 = value.slice(length/2, length-1);
        }
        return value;
      });

      scope.changed = function() {
        // Set the model value from inside the directive
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.data.input1 + ' + ' + scope.data.input2);
      }
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.data = {};
    }
  };
})
```